# "if IE" not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, comments

thanks for reading.

I have a simple problem that i can't solve. I just need to have a html map with Jquery fadeIn and fadeOut effects. I got it and it works everywhere except with IE8.

So i just wanna add a pure javascript already tested and working just when IE8 is present.

Obviously i tried writing this code but is not working even with a simple alert after the IE comment.

Can you help please?

Here's the code, thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">var runFancy = true;</script>
            <!--[if IE]>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                runFancy = false;
                alert(runFancy);
                function showIt(name)
                {

                document.getElementById('map_image').src='immagini/distributori/8/'.concat(name).concat('.png');
                document.getElementById('map_image').style.display='block';


                }

                function hideIt()
                {

                document.getElementById('map_image').src='immagini/distributori/8/map.png';

                };

            </script>
            <![endif]-->
```

Here's the code for other browsers

```
            <!--[if !IE]><!-->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //alert('hi'); not working even just this
                if (runFancy) {
                    function showIt(name)
                {


                document.getElementById('map_image').src='immagini/distributori/single/'.concat(name).concat('_single.png');


                $('#mapon').fadeIn(400);



                }

                function hideIt()
                {

                $('#mapon').fadeOut(300);
                };
                }
            </script>
             <!--<![endif]-->
```

even this is not working, any advice?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:red">

<h1>Ciao</h1>


<!--[if IE]>
<style language="text/css">
body{background-color:black;}

</style>
<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

not working with every IE version.

Comment: seems correct to me!!!!

Comment: me too man but not working even if i write:

Comment: <!--[if IE]>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                
                alert('hi');
<!--<![endif]-->

Comment: but why is it commented?

Comment: Your ending tag looks a bit off, I think: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('hi');</script>
<![endif]-->

Comment: Note, I did add a condition that will apply to only IE versions less than 9. You might find IE 9 or 10 will execute your script properly.

Comment: Hi Chris, i made wrong copy paste, the close tag is correct as you can see in my complete code, anyway adding

Comment: <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script type="text/javascript">alert('hi');</script> <![endif]-->

is not working

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9">    <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="IE8.js">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: not working :( even if i just write in the header or in the body this:

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('hi');
<![endif]-->

nothing happens with ie8 ie9 and ie10!

Answer (score 0):

the code you have should be working but if you want to target just IE 8 put IE 8 instead of just IE like so

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
do stuff
<![endif]-->
```

edit: removed depreciated jquery solution

Comment: jQuery browser is removed as of 1.9 so that will only work with older version of jQuery.

Comment: my problem is not on jquery, i made a simple code like:


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:red">

<h1>Ciao</h1>


<!--[if IE]>
<style language="text/css">
body{background-color:black;}

</style>
<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>